# RFM69W Channel mechanism

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to understand how the channels for the RFM69W is created, if there is more than one. The [manual](http://www.hoperf.com/upload/rf/RFM69W-V1.3.pdf) specify "channelized operation", and I find channel bandwidths and that at 16 tap channel filter is used(3.4.6). There is also values for suppression levels of other channels (2.4.4). What I don't find is a description of how the channels are created out.

That the channels have different bands is what makes most sense to me, but I can't see how I can find the frequency from the channel number. Initially I also thought that the NetworkID(Sync word, 5.5.2) was related to channels, but now I think that is based on the package data. I also can't find anything describing how to change channels. [Update, see below]

Background: I'm using [LowPowerLabs RFM69 library](https://github.com/LowPowerLab/RFM69) with monteinos and are investigating if I can use the RFM69W to intercept packages from my outside thermometer, [similar to this](http://rayshobby.net/reverse-engineer-wireless-temperature-humidity-rain-sensors-part-1/).

Edit: Via [this post](https://lowpowerlab.com/forum/rf-range-antennas-rfm69-library/node-rfm69-id-assignment-in-500x-access-point-network/) I discovered that the library have a setFrequency method, so that may mean that channels are made manually by specifying center frequency and bandwith.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much you can set whatever center frequency you want (to a precision of 61Hz) and whatever bandwidth you feel. All this is dependent on your bit rate and partially on the modulation scheme - OOK isn't spectrally efficient while 4FSK uses half the bandwidth of 2FSK for the same data rate.

If you had say, <10kHz bandwidth, then you could possibly fit 100 channels in a 1MHz span, while a 300kHz bandwidth would only get you 3 channels in the same frequency span, that's why it doesn't specifically list things like "Channel x is on frequency y" as the RFM69 doesn't have fixed channel widths. The aren't (to the best of my knowledge) any official channel designations in the unlicensed ISM bands, every application is different so most of these little radio units are built with that flexibility in mind.